# Loading up dynamically created list when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a dynamic list and am trying to load it up when the page loads up. I have written the script and tested it out but it does not seem to be working for some reason.

CODE

```
<script>
     var fruits = ["apple","pear","banana","orange"];

     function showList(){
    list = document.createElement("LI");
   list.setAttribute("href","#");
   for(i=0;i<fruits.length;i++){
        list = fruits[i];
     }


   }

   </script>

   <ul id="list-container" onload="showList();">


  </ul>
```

fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/88vo6vb8/

Comment: where you are adding the list items to your dom, and use `window.onload` instead and call your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxanL468/)
and code snippet below. Based on the answer of @Shalitha Suranga, I made a small addition.

```html
<script>
var fruits = ["apple","pear","banana","orange"];

window.onload = () => {
  for(let i=0;i<fruits.length;i++){
   liA=document.createElement("a");
    liA.setAttribute("href","#");
    list = document.createElement("LI");
    list.innerHTML = fruits[i];
    liA.appendChild(list);
    document.getElementById('list-container').appendChild(liA);
  }


}

</script>

<ul id="list-container">
  
  
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i get it now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to work with `window.onload` event and move the element creation code inside to the loop as per below. And also use `element.innerHTML` to set the text for each `li` element.

```html
<script>
var fruits = ["apple","pear","banana","orange"];

window.onload = () => {
  for(let i=0;i<fruits.length;i++){
    list = document.createElement("LI");
    list.setAttribute("href","#");
    list.innerHTML = fruits[i];
    document.getElementById('list-container').appendChild(list);
  }


}

</script>

<ul id="list-container">
  
  
</ul>
```

Comment: `innerText` may make more sense than `innerHTML` here.

Comment: But this way i cant make the list hyperlinked like i want to with the .setAttribute

Comment: you cannot add `href` attribute directly to `li` in order to make it hyperlinked. you have to add child `a` element with `href` as you want